# Set properties file in JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss7.x

I have configured the properies file in JBoss AS 6 using properties-service.xml .
 here is my configuration for JBoss AS 6-->

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" 
 name="jboss:type=Service,name=SystemProperties">
<attribute name="URLList">
  here is path for properties file.
</attribute>
</mbean>
```

Now i have installed the JBoss AS 7 server on my machine. How can I deploy or configure these properties AS 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

System Properties can be set in the `standalone.xml`, `host.xml` or `domain.xml` files depending on whether you are running a standalone instance, or configuring a member of a managed domain. Check out the following JBoss community documentation links:

Link: [JBoss AS 7 Admin Guide - System Properties](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-SystemProperties)

Link: [JBoss AS7 System Properties article](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SystemProperties)

Answer (score 4):

You can also configure properties using the `-P={properties file}` syntax, which is very useful. Then in any of the `standalone.xml` files, you can use `${your.property}` type syntax.

i.e. in /bin you can run:

```
standalone.bat -P=mysettings.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

After load the properties, u can see it at

localhost:8080 > Configuration > Environment Properties